ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection' when trying to install in Google Collab 2024
Hellok,
I am trying to build my first object detection model using google collab tensorflow object detection api (not sure if this is important but the model im using is faster_rcnn_resnet101_v1_640x640_coco17) but i am having installation issues and dont understand how to fix them. I have all the data sorted in the correct formats, and all the config files e.t.c all done. I am just having this error, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'. Here is the install scripts i am running with comments:
# Installing TensorFlow and required libraries
!pip install tensorflow==2.12.0
!pip install tensorflow-addons
!pip install cython
!pip install contextlib2
!pip install pillow
!pip install lxml
!pip install matplotlib
!pip install numpy
!pip install opencv-python-headless
!pip install tf-slim


# Cloning the TensorFlow models repository
!git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/tensorflow/models

# Compiling protobufs and install the object detection package
!apt-get install -y protobuf-compiler python-pil python-lxml python-tk
!pip install Cython contextlib2 pillow lxml matplotlib

# Compiling the protobuf libraries
%cd /content/models/research/
!protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.

# Installing the object detection module
!pip install . -q object_detection/packages/tf2
!pip install tensorflow-addons

# Verifing the installation
!python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py

And here is the error message
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow==2.12.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (2.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=1.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorflow==2.12.0) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: astunparse>=1.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorflow==2.12.0) (1.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: flatbuffers>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorflow==2.12.0) (24.3.25)
Requirement already satisfied: gast<=0.4.0,>=0.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorflow==2.12.0) (0.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-pasta>=0.1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorflow==2.12.0) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio<2.0,>=1.24.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorflow==2.12.0) (1.64.1)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py>=2.9.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorflow==2.12.0) (3.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jax>=0.3.15 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorflow==2.12.0) (0.4.26)
Requirement already satisfied: keras<2.13,>=2.12.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorflow==2.12.0) (2.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: libclang>=13.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorflow==2.12.0) (18.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.24,>=1.22 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorflow==2.12.0) (1.23.5)
Requirement already satisfied: opt-einsum>=2.3.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorflow==2.12.0) (3.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorflow==2.12.0) (24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.20.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorflow==2.12.0) (3.20.3)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorflow==2.12.0) (71.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.12.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorflow==2.12.0) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorflow==2.12.0) (2.12.3)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-estimator<2.13,>=2.12.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorflow==2.12.0) (2.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorflow==2.12.0) (2.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorflow==2.12.0) (4.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt<1.15,>=1.11.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorflow==2.12.0) (1.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem>=0.23.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorflow==2.12.0) (0.37.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel<1.0,>=0.23.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from astunparse>=1.6.0->tensorflow==2.12.0) (0.43.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ml-dtypes>=0.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from jax>=0.3.15->tensorflow==2.12.0) (0.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.9 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from jax>=0.3.15->tensorflow==2.12.0) (1.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth<3,>=1.6.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow==2.12.0) (2.27.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth-oauthlib<1.1,>=0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow==2.12.0) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow==2.12.0) (3.6)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3,>=2.21.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow==2.12.0) (2.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard-data-server<0.8.0,>=0.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow==2.12.0) (0.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow==2.12.0) (3.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools<6.0,>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from google-auth<3,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow==2.12.0) (5.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from google-auth<3,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow==2.12.0) (0.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa<5,>=3.1.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from google-auth<3,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow==2.12.0) (4.9)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib<1.1,>=0.5->tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow==2.12.0) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow==2.12.0) (3.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow==2.12.0) (3.7)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow==2.12.0) (2.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow==2.12.0) (2024.7.4)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from werkzeug>=1.0.1->tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow==2.12.0) (2.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1<0.7.0,>=0.4.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth<3,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow==2.12.0) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib<1.1,>=0.5->tensorboard<2.13,>=2.12->tensorflow==2.12.0) (3.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-addons in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (0.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorflow-addons) (24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: typeguard<3.0.0,>=2.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorflow-addons) (2.13.3)
Requirement already satisfied: cython in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (3.0.10)
Requirement already satisfied: contextlib2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (21.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (9.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (4.9.4)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (3.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: contourpy>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from matplotlib) (1.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from matplotlib) (0.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from matplotlib) (4.53.1)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from matplotlib) (1.4.5)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.20 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from matplotlib) (1.23.5)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from matplotlib) (24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from matplotlib) (9.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.3.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from matplotlib) (3.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7->matplotlib) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (1.23.5)
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python-headless in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (4.10.0.84)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from opencv-python-headless) (1.23.5)
Requirement already satisfied: tf-slim in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.2.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tf-slim) (1.4.0)
fatal: destination path 'models' already exists and is not an empty directory.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-pil
E: Unable to locate package python-lxml
Requirement already satisfied: Cython in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (3.0.10)
Requirement already satisfied: contextlib2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (21.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (9.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (4.9.4)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (3.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: contourpy>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from matplotlib) (1.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from matplotlib) (0.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from matplotlib) (4.53.1)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from matplotlib) (1.4.5)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.20 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from matplotlib) (1.23.5)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from matplotlib) (24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.3.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from matplotlib) (3.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7->matplotlib) (1.16.0)
/content/models/research
ERROR: Directory '.' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-addons in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (0.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorflow-addons) (24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: typeguard<3.0.0,>=2.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tensorflow-addons) (2.13.3)
2024-08-04 10:28:33.755321: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2024-08-04 10:28:33.805354: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2024-08-04 10:28:33.805919: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX512F FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-08-04 10:28:34.816725: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/content/models/research/object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py", line 24, in 
from object_detection.builders import model_builder
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'
I tried reinstalling everything and online tutorials to fix, but they dont seem to get the same issue. Maybe its because the tutorials are out of date? I am not sure.
